# CollectionViewSource.Filter doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, events, c#-4.0, wpfdatagrid

I have a window in my application with following resources:

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Data:IssueRecords x:Key="DataSource"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="DataCollection" Source="{StaticResource DataSource}"
                              Filter="CollectionViewSource_Filter">
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

There is a standard event handler - a method, called CollectionViewSource_Filter and DataGrid, to apply filter to. After my window loads, everything works perfectly, including filters.

For applying filters, I call a ReloadGrid method...

```
    private void ReloadGrid(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(GridData.ItemsSource).Refresh();
    }
```

But, when user does any action, which makes changes to my database (delete, modify or create new), I need to reload those data sources, so I call...

```
    private void ReloadDataSources()
    {
        var dataSource = this.FindResource("DataSource") as IStockRecords;
        dataSource.ReloadData();

        var dataCollection = this.FindResource("DataCollection") as CollectionViewSource;
        dataCollection = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = dataSource };
        dataCollection.Filter += new FilterEventHandler(CollectionViewSource_Filter);

        Binding binding = new Binding() { Source = dataCollection };
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(GridData, DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
    }
```

I think, I do everything, what is needed to read actual data from database and reload the datasources in my window. But when I use any filter, after I call ReloadDataSources(), the filter event is not being used anymore. I debugged a source code and Refresh method doesn't invoke CollectionViewSource_Filter, even when I set FilterEventHandler...

Am i missing anything?
Thanks, JiKra

Comment: Have you tried updating the source and database rather than refreshing the source.  I know it seems like a hassle but that is what I do do for scalability.

Comment: I update database via insert, update, or delete. Then I call dataSource.ReloadData(), which calls sql select to retrieve actual data.

Comment: I understand that is what you do.  I am suggesting you update both rather than just the database and reload.

Comment: ReloadData() method clears the list of data and retrieves fresh data from database via select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, there seems to be a problem when I recreated CollectionViewSource object. So, the final version is...

```
private void ReloadDataSources()
{
    var dataSource = this.FindResource("DataSource") as IStockRecords;
    dataSource.ReloadData();
    var dataCollection = this.FindResource("DataCollection") as CollectionViewSource;
    //here I just had to refresh collection's view, not to create a new one
    dataCollection.View.Refresh();
    Binding binding = new Binding() { Source = dataCollection };
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(GridData, DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
}
```

Thank you both for your effort...
JiKra

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset your default view after you modify the data source.

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(GridData.ItemsSource).Refresh();
```

Try this....

```
    private void ReloadDataSources()
{
    var dataSource = this.FindResource("DataSource") as IStockRecords;
    dataSource.ReloadData();

    var dataCollection = this.FindResource("DataCollection") as CollectionViewSource;
    // Remove the current event handler
    dataCollection.Filter -= new FilterEventHandler(CollectionViewSource_Filter);
    // Set your new data source
    dataCollection = new CollectionViewSource() { Source = dataSource };
    // Read your handler
    dataCollection.Filter += new FilterEventHandler(CollectionViewSource_Filter);
    // Now reset your filter
    dataCollection .GetDefaultView(GridData.ItemsSource).Refresh();
    Binding binding = new Binding() { Source = dataCollection };
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(GridData, DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I call this function.
ReloadDataSources();
ReloadGrid(null, null);